# Synchronize SFDC object inserts with external web service

Tags: integration, rest

I want to integrate my salesforce org with a tool named Moogsoft . Whenever a record is created at my end.
 I have to update the other environment(moogsoft) using the below URL
https://etamtsvpmoogdv01:8080/graze/v1/addSigCorrelationInfo?auth_token=cc63c187531b46e3a2abfa716a34bc74&sitn_id=&service_name=Remedyforce&resource_id=

auth_token in above URL can be fetched using the below link
https://etamtsvpmoogdv01:8080/graze/v1/authenticate?username=graze&password=graze
This link returns auth_token

situation_id : It is one of the field at my end(at salesforce side)

RF_ticket_id : the name/serial number of the record that is created at salesforce side.

Please let me know how this can be done ,if any more information is required please let me know.

Thanks alot :)

Comment: welcome to the community.  while posting your question it is always good to post following things. 1. what you have done so far? 2. your current code? 3. what issue you are facing with your code. any exception etc.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a trigger which will call future method. First future method will callout to retrieve auth_token, then will callout again to actually update the records.

Please note, that you will have to think how you store credentials within SF.

Also, looks like addresses you provided are internal, so you will need to expose them to the public web.

Comment: How can i store the code/value  that i am receiving from the first callout  and send it back in form of url...do i need to give one more end point as 2nd url..

Comment: If it's not part of the same transaction you could store it in cache.